# drawing multiple TGraphs in ROOT

Tags: c++, plot, frameworks, root-framework

Is there any command to generate multiple graphs from the command line / terminal. I have a `.root` file which contains processed graph objects so I am able to draw a single graph at a time with the command

```
pAngRateAlld_S0_M0->Draw("Hist");
```

when the file is opened with `root -l maplot_20070101_4m.root`

Answer (score 4):

After you open your file with:

```
root -l filename.root
```

you can draw a TGraph with:

```
myGraph->Draw("apl");
```

or with other options like:

```
myGraph->Draw("Hist");
```

the important thing is to realize that this creates a default canvas. If you try to draw another graph it will draw it in the same canvas, i.e. it will replace the last one.

to have multiple graphs there are few options:

1) one graph per canvas: you need to create a canvas for each graph before drawing it:

```
TCanvas *c1=new TCanvas();
myGraph1->Draw("apl");
TCanvas *c2=new TCanvas();
myGraph2->Draw("apl");
etc.
```

2) multiple graphs in the same plot:

```
myGraph1->Draw("apl");
myGraph2->Draw("pl same");
myGraph3->Draw("pl same");
```

3) splitting the canvas:

```
TCanvas *c1=new TCanvas();
c1->Divide(3,3); // divides the canvas into three rows and three columns
c1->cd(1);
myGraph1->Draw("apl");
c1->cd(2);
myGraph2->Draw("apl");
```